# Latency in Twilio call response

Tags: twilio

I am have a Twilio phone number which is connected to an endpoint which i am hosting on my local host, which is put live on the internet using ngrok.

My code is written in TWiML, and uses express JS to host. It will take user input, and repeat it back to the user. Everything is working, but the actual response time from the number is really slow!

Here is a typical interaction:

1. User: Ring Twilio Number
2. Twilio: welcome to your phone app…
3. User: “some speech input “”
4. Twilio: **Takes 10 seconds to respond**

What could be causing this large delay in response time?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Twilio [Request Inspector](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136407-Debugging-your-application) in your Twilio console, for the specific call involved, and the response time for the request by Twilio to your application. It is possible your application is taking ~10 seconds to respond. If so, you need to look deeper into your application, to determine what is causing this delay.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue today myself.  I'm using C# and found that if I specify the input types with speech first then there is a huge (~10 second) delay.  If I put DTMF first then everything works well and the "timeout" and "speechTimeout" settings are respected as expected.
[image]